# JSONModel returns nil

Tags: objective-c, json, nsarray, jsonmodel

I'mm using JSONModel to get the JSON from the URL.
It's a very simple object, containing only 2 strings - "name" and "url".

First I made the Object Model:

```
@protocol
Tutorial
@end
@interface Tutorial : JSONModel
@property (nonatomic, strong)   NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong)   NSString *url;
@end
```

Then Object Feed:

```
#import "JSONModel.h"
#import "Tutorial.h"
@interface TutorialFeed : JSONModel
@property (nonatomic, strong)   NSArray <Tutorial> *tutorials;
@end
```

and then in MasterViewController.m:

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "TutorialFeed.h"
#import "JSONModelLib.h"

@interface MasterViewController () {
  TutorialFeed *feed;
  TutorialFeed *testFeed;
}
@end
@implementation MasterViewController
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    feed = [[TutorialFeed alloc]

initFromURLWithString:@"http://api.matematikfessor.dk/apps/teacher_videos"
       completion:^(JSONModel *model, JSONModelError *err) {
           NSLog(@"Tutorials %@", feed.tutorials);
       }];
 }
 @end
```

The problem is, I get returned nil in my log :(
Im not sure why is this happening, because I managed to fetch data from JSON from this URL:
[Kiwa URL](http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/search.json?status=fundraising)

All that done, following this [tutorial](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/how-to-fetch-and-parse-json-by-using-data-models/)

Im not sure what am I doing wrong. 
Does anybody has any clue ?

Comment: There is no tutorials object in that JSON response. Did you check it?

Comment: Guys, Im new with obj-c development.
first, Im not sure what do you mean with "There is no tutorials object in that JSON response."
second, what do you mean with "inspecting and reporting the error variable err"

I might have asked a dumb questions now, but after years in Android, it's hard to switch to obj-c. At least for me.

Comment: ERROR variable says:
2013-09-19 11:30:16.024 EduLabTutorial[48084:c07] Tutorials Error Domain=JSONModelErrorDomain Code=1 "Invalid JSON data. Malformed JSON, server response invalid or other reason for invalid input to a JSONModel class." UserInfo=0x8060550 {NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid JSON data. Malformed JSON, server response invalid or other reason for invalid input to a JSONModel class.}

Comment: sorry i am thinking in a wrong way about that tutorial object.

Comment: Yeah but it is strange, how did you come up with "{"error":true,"loggedin":false,"data":null}"
because I get a propper JSON when I type in url in browser

Comment: But if you want to do parse and get data you just use these two lines NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.matematikfessor.dk/apps/teacher_videos"]];
NSArray * tutorials =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kInvalidID error:nil];

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Explanation:**

First of all JSONModel expects your JSON top object to be a dictionary, only that way it can match its keys to a model's properties.

Your model called TutorialFeed expects to be fed JSON matching the property name "tutorials".This means your JSON feed must be in the form:

> { "tutorials": [{obj1}, {obj2}, {obj3}, ...] }

What you have in fact at: http://api.matematikfessor.dk/apps/teacher_videos is

> [{obj1}, {obj2}, {obj3}]

That's why your model instance is in fact "nil" because the JSON structure didn't match what your model expects.

**Solution:**

If you have an array at the top of your JSON feed (like the one on the URL you use) you have two options:

1) introduce a new key in your JSON feed - i.e. alter the JSON to be in the form of {"tutorials": [obj1, obj2, etc...]}

2) You can use another method to parse the JSON feed. Look up the [docs here](http://jsonmodel.com/docs/Classes/JSONModel.html#//api/name/arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries:) and use the static method that parses a list of objects:

```
#import "JSONModel+networking.h"
...
[JSONHTTPClient   
  getJSONFromURLWithString:@"http://api.matematikfessor.dk/apps/teacher_videos"
  completion:^(id feed, JSONModelError *err) {
    NSArray* tutorials = [Tutorial arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries: feed];
    NSLog(@"tutorials: %@", tutorials);
  }];
```

Comment: This method can be used if I am returning a single result, correct? This is returning multiple tutorials? I am working with a JSON object that returns 1 set of data inside contains multiple objects and an object of arrays.