# Parsing json in iOS NULL

Tags: ios, json, null

trying to parse JSON from http://sec.kimonolabs.com/companies with the JSONModel framework but the problem is that values logged come out as null.

I am trying to output the name and cik of some companies with the SEC API on a table view but currently there is no output because the values are null.

The .m files for the below code are just default with no custom code.

Any help appreciated!

LoanModel.h

```
#import "JSONModel.h"
//#import "LocationModel.h"

@protocol LoanModel @end
@interface LoanModel : JSONModel

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* cik;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* display_name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* name;
//@property (strong, nonatomic) LocationModel* location;

@end
```

KivaFeed.h

```
#import "JSONModel.h"
#import "LoanModel.h"

@interface KivaFeed : JSONModel

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<LoanModel>* company;

@end
```

MasterViewController.h

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "JSONModelLib.h"
#import "KivaFeed.h"

@interface MasterViewController () {
    KivaFeed* _feed;

}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //show loader view
    //[HUD showUIBlockingIndicatorWithText:@"Fetching JSON"];

    //fetch the feed
    _feed = [[KivaFeed alloc] initFromURLWithString:@"http://sec.kimonolabs.com/companies" completion:^(JSONModel *model, JSONModelError *err) {

                                             //hide the loader view
                                             //[HUD hideUIBlockingIndicator];

                                             //json fetched
                                              NSLog(@"loans: %@", _feed.company);
                                             NSLog(@"loans: %@", _feed.company);

                                             //reload the table view
                                             [self.tableView reloadData];



                                         }];
}

#pragma mark - table methods
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _feed.company.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    LoanModel* loan = _feed.company[indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ and %@", loan.name, loan.cik];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: initFromURLWithString can you provide the defination for this method
initFromURLWithString is not present in JSONModel

Comment: I think the problem is that there is no root NAME for the array

Comment: You are using the custom asynchronous init method of JSONModel “initFromURLWithString:completion:“. The initialiser method fetches the JSON at the provided URL, and when done, updates the model object and invokes the provided block.

Comment: Thats what i got from the tutorial i was working on but i just found a another question on stack overflow similar to mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890762/jsonmodel-returns-nil

Comment: I tried using the above solution and it works for me.